# Worry about the 4s?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode8, iphone-4

Totally newbie here...I have been working on auto layout using stacks and constraints with X code 8 and I have a very good understanding of how it works. I can get my layouts to render across all sizes in the sim looking as expected.

My one issue is that I can easily make layouts that looks good for 5 through 7 plus...but when I try to make the 4S work, it just kinda screws everything up in regard to the spacing of the layout for the other models....it still works and looks as expected, but because the 4s is so small, it ends up leaving a lot of space in the other sizes.

Should I just not worry about the 4s and make sure that my other sizes render the way I want?  When I submit my app will this cause it to be rejected?

Comment: Is there no way you could have a custom layout just for that screen size?

Comment: Not fully supporting 4s is not reason enough to be rejected. But you should consider who your target is. In Latin America for example, iPhones 4s are still pretty common, so dropping support for that would be a bad idea. If your target is only the US maybe you can stop worrying about it.

Comment: [All iPhone only apps need to run on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#hardware-compatibility) within iPhone simulator. And currently iPad simulates iPhone 4S size. You can find some reports that apps which do not function on iPad has been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

From the following link you can see that there is only about 2% of people are only using iPhone 4s. So if you targetting above this device its ok.
https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/

Apple's latest iOS  will not support iPhone 4S, which has been supported from iOS 5 all the way to iOS 9.Apple announced that the iPhone 4S will not support iOS 10 due to hardware limitations.
As mentioned in comments you can go for a custom layout for that scree size if needed.